# Нужна необычная карусель

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток. Очень нужна такого рода карусель:

[image: img]

Если у кого есть на примете такая, буду благодарен. Думаю, смысл работы карусели понятен.

Comment: а чем она необычна карусель ? тем что в thumbnail не то что показывается в главной области ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Плагин: [Jquery MS Carousel](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-ms-carousel)

Пример Карусели: [carousel/gallery](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/carousel/gallery.html)

---

Плагин2: [jQuery Infinite Carousel](http://www.catchmyfame.com/catchmyfame-jquery-plugins/jquery-infinite-carousel-plugin/)

Пример Карусели2: [gallery](http://www.catchmyfame.com/jquery/infinitecarousel3/demo/d3.html)

Answer (score 2):

Думаю этот вариант вам должен подойти [caroufredsel](http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/examples/intermediate-carousels.php). Придется только изменить стиль под ваши требования и добавить контролсы путем использования конфигурации плагина.

Comment: ну почти то,как сделать так, если много картинок, то мелкие картинки запихивались как карусель.

Comment: можете более подробно описать суть так как ничего не понял )